# How to solve equation in integer numbers?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, diophantine-equations

I have following equation:
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2 = 2 x y z v.$$
How can I solve this one? Roots should be integer numbers.

Edit: I tried to prove, that given equation don't have solutions. I fixed $z, v$ variables. Then task boils down to finding intersection between paraboloid and saddle. Unfortunately, it is hard way. Maybe there are another ways/patterns for solving similar equations?

Comment: Александр, здесь правилами сайта оговорено, что Вы должны показать свои попытки решения этой задачи, иначе вопрос будут минусовать и закрывать

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Outline*: It will turn out that the only solution is with all the variables equal to $0$.

The right-hand side is even. So it is clear our variables are not all odd.

If two are odd and two are even, the left-hand side is congruent to $2$ modulo $4$, but the right-hand side is divisible by $4$, impossible.

So all the variables are even. Let $x=2x_1$, $y=2y_1$, and so on.

Substitute in our equation and simplify. We get $$x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2+v_1^2=8x_1y_1z_1v_1.$$

Now repeat the argument. We find that $x_1,y_1,z_1,v_1$ are all even. Let $x_1=2x_2$, $y_1=2y_2$, and so on. We get
$$x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2+v_2^2=32x_2y_2z_2v_2.$$

Continue. We conclude that each of $x,y,z,v$ is divisible by arbitrarily high powers of $2$, so all of them are $0$.

*Remark*: This sort of argument is usually called an *infinite descent* argument. It is ordinarily credited to Fermat. It is essentially an induction argument.

If you prefer, you can write it up as follows. If there is a solution with the variables not  all equal to $0$, then there is a solution with $|x|+|y|+|z|+|v|$ positive and minimal. But then $(x_1,y_1,z_1,v_1)$ is a solution with sum of the absolute values greater than $0$ but less than $|x|+|y|+|z|+|v|$: Contradiction!

Comment: Brilliant description

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand, there are infinitely many solutions to 
$$  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2 = 4 xyzv,$$
occurring in a tree similar to the tree of [Markov Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number). It took me a while to find out, but most Markov things are the same person.

There are also infinitely many solutions to 
$$  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2 = 4 xyzv,$$
although this time all the variables are even, dividing all of them by $2$ gives a quadruple in the first tree.

For details, see  [HURWITZ](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf)

Comment: Interesting approach. Unfortunately I cannot understand language of article (I am native Russian)

Comment: @АлександрЛысенко then I will just describe it. To solve $$ x_1^2 + \cdots x_n^2 = x \, x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n $$ in positive integers, we must have $x \leq n,$ also every tree of solutions has a "fundamental" solution with $$  \max {2 x_i^2} \leq x  \, x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n $$ He gives enough inequalities so that it is a finite search to find fundamental solution for a fixed $a,x$ or show nonexistence.